# Make Ajax call to C# Controller Method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

This is the code in my javascript file called "data handling.js" located in a folder called "JS":

```
document.getElementById('submit-new-project').addEventListener("click", function () {
    var ProjectName = document.getElementById('new-project').value;
    if (ProjectName) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Controllers/HomeController/AddProject",
            data: {"ProjectName": ProjectName},
            success: function () {
                hideElement("add-button-popup");
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown)
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("Text Field Must Not Be Empty");
    }
})
```

And here is my controller method:

```
public partial class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public static void AddProject(string ProjectName)
    {
        using (AutomationMethodDirectoryEntities db = new AutomationMethodDirectoryEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                PROJECT project = new PROJECT();
                project.ProjectName = ProjectName;
                db.PROJECTS.Add(project);
                db.SaveChanges();;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

The controller method is located in "Adders.cs" which is a partial class to "HomeController.cs" in the "Controllers" folder. Both the "JS" and "Controllers" folders are at the root level of the project. I have tried many variations of this ajax call and my biggest problem is with the URL. No matter what I try, I am always getting a 404 error because the server can't find the requested URL.

I've tried changing it to:

```
url: "Controllers/HomeController/AddProject"
url: "/Controllers/HomeController/AddProject"
url: "../Controllers/HomeController/AddProject"
url: "Home/AddProject"
url: "/Home/AddProject"
url: "../Home/AddProject"
url: "@(Url.Action(AddProject, HomeController))"
```

And I've swapped "HomeController" with "Adders" in different variations.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there anything I need to add/change to my controller method?

**EDIT**

Here is my "RouteConfig.cs" that I haven't made any changes to yet:

```
namespace RTCAD
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your routers configuration of your ASP.NET application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When calling your `AddProject` action, ASP.NET MVC creates an instance of the controller (using `ControllerFactory`), and since your method is static, it is not related to any instance, and thus, it will not be called by MVC.

Remove the static from the method declaration and use `/Home/AddProject` as the URL.

Comment: Holy cow, thank you! I've been at this for way too long.

Comment: We've all been there :)